# eBPF: insert a new inner map to `BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH_OF_MAPS`?

Tags: bpf, ebpf, linux-security-module

I am trying to implement LSM BPF programs and I want to use `BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH_OF_MAPS` to store information for each super block as the `sb_alloc_security` LSM hook is triggered. For example, I want to define the map as:

```
struct bpf_map_def SEC("SBMap") outer_map = {
    .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH_OF_MAPS,
    .key_size = sizeof(uuid_t),   // super block unique identifier
    .value_size = sizeof(__u32),  // must be u32 because it is inner map id
    .max_entries = 1024,          // for now, let's assume we care about only 1024 super blocks
};
```

I want to use the super block's UUID as the key to the `outer_map` and every time a new super block is allocated, I would like to create a new inner map, something like:

```
SEC("lsm/sb_alloc_security")
int BPF_PROG(sb_alloc_security, struct super_block *sb) {
    uuid_t key = sb->s_uuid; // use super block UUID as key to the outer_map
    // If key does not exist in outer_map,
    // create a new inner map and insert it
    // into the outer_map with the key
}
```

But it seems like maps can be created only in user space. Is there any workaround?

Comment: What are you planning to put in the inner map?

Comment: I am planning to map an inode (that "belongs" to a super block) to some information about that inode in the inner map.@pchaigno

Comment: Couldn't you use a structure with both the super block's UUID and the inode as the key to a hashmap instead of using a map of map?

Comment: @pchaigno That's in fact what I am planning to do now that using a map of maps seems to be much more involved than I would like it to be (although I do think in my use case, a map of maps is more logically "clean"). Thanks anyways!

Comment: Why do you consider a map of map cleaner? With a single map, you'll do a single lookup and use less memory compared to a map of map.

Comment: I agree that a single lookup is operationally easier and a single map uses less memory, but I consider it _logically_ cleaner to use a map of maps because each super block maps to a number of inodes it "manages" (i.e., inner map) and a system can have many super blocks (i.e., outer map).

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, **BPF maps can only be created from userspace**, including inner maps of maps-in-maps structures. If you could create maps from the BPF programs, it would essentially enable dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: But I can't dynamically insert a new inner map in the `int BPF_PROG(sb_alloc_security, struct super_block *sb)` function, can I?

Comment: From userspace you can, but that will have the same limitations as creating the inner map from userspace.

Comment: Sounds like you _can_ do it with `bpf_map_update_elem()`, but it may not be the most efficient thing for the described use case. See discussion on [bpf mailing list](https://lore.kernel.org/bpf/878sdlpv92.fsf@toke.dk/T/#e9bac624324ffd3efb0c9f600426306e3a40ec7b5).